# Cronjob to send temperature alert via SMS

Tags: linux, cron

I am doing a small project on my RPi. I already created a website that shows the temperature. The temperature is updated every minute with a cronjob and stored in a .txt file.

Now I want to be notified when the temperature rises above 30 degrees Celsius via SMS. I already set up a HSDPA USB Dongle and I am able to send SMS's via Terminal.

Can someone please help me to write a cronjob, that reads the temperature out of the .txt file and if the temperature is above 30 degrees Celsius it should send me an SMS. The command for sending SMS is this:

```
echo -e "To: 004917112312312\n\nTEXTMESSAGE" > /var/www/sms/outbox/testsms.txt
```

Comment: the .txt file looks like ths: Raspberry Pi wiringPi DHT22 reader www.lolware.net Humidity = 61.40 % Temperature = 25.00 *C

Comment: This info belongs in your question not in the comments. Please edit your question and add this information.

Answer (score 2):

That would be

```
0 * * * * *  /bin/bash -c 'if [ "`cat /path/to/temp.txt`" -gt "30" ]; then echo -e "To: 004917112312312\n\nTEXTMESSAGE" > /var/www/sms/outbox/testsms.txt; fi'
```

Replace `/path/to/temp.txt` with the file containing the temperature value, and configure the alert frequency as you see fit (this one will fire every hour).

Comment: the .txt file looks like ths:   Raspberry Pi wiringPi DHT22 reader
www.lolware.net
Humidity = 61.40 % Temperature = 25.00 *C

Comment: @MrGT_ and if that information was in the question, I could have written a much more useful answer, couldn't I?